# If I modify JS/CSS in GPL-licensed WordPress themes/plugins for my website, do I have to include all the changes?

Tags: gpl

If I modify JavaScript/CSS in WordPress themes/plugins (GPL licensed) for my website, do I have to include all of the changes in the header of the file? I know that use css/js files in a website is a distribute operation for opensource license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The GPL requires a notice *that* you changed a file, but the notice doesn't have to include *what* changes were made.

If your changes were large and/or creative enough to be protected by copyright (and the bar is not very high on that), it would technically be enough notice to add a copyright statement to the files for your copyright.

For people looking at your adapted version, it would be nice if you give a one or two line description of your changes, but you don't have to be complete.

Comment: If you want to record changes (not needed by licence), then use a revision control system (svn, hg, git).